# What is the most efficient way to prepend a `&str` to a `String`?

Tags: rust

What is the most efficient way to prepend a `&str` to a `String`? Right now I am allocating a new `String` and pushing to it:

```rust
fn push_front(s: String, prefix: &str) -> String {
  let prefix = prefix.to_owned();
  prefix.push_str(&s);
  prefix
}
```

Is there a more efficient way? I don't see a `String::push_front` function in the standard library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`String::insert_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.insert_str):

```rust
s.insert_str(0, prefix);
```

Instead of allocating a new `String` *and* (potentially) allocating for the push, `insert_str` reserves capacity in the underlying vector and shifts the elements of `s` to the right. If the `String` already has sufficient capacity for `prefix`, it avoids the allocation altogether. This means it will only require *at most* one allocation, rather than two.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`String::insert_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.insert_str):

```
fn push_front(s: String, prefix: &str) -> String {
  s.insert_str(0, prefix);
  s
}
```

This will use 0-1 allocations instead of the 1-2 in the original.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a String::push_front, but there is String::insert_str.

```
fn main(){
    let a = "foo";
    let mut b = "bar".to_owned();
    b.insert_str(0,a);
    dbg!{b};
}
```